# Is there a printing lab that post prints direct to customer without the invoice?

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, photolabs

Is there an online printing service, (like [photobox](http://www.photobox.co.uk/)) that I can use to print and ship prints directly to customers so that I don't even handle them. If I use a normal online printing service, they will send an invoice. Since I will be charging the customers more than I pay for the prints, is there a service that doesn't send the invoice?

Bonus points if they send the prints with my branding instead of theirs.

Bonus bonus points if they have labs in multiple major countries (USA, UK etc). Otherwise, just listing a companies in each country is fine

This isn't for printing wedding photos or anything important like that, just general quality, mass market snaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.pwinty.com

This in an API for printing and shipping photos, and offers worldwide shipping.

They let you specify your own custom branding, and invoices to be included within the package- sounds like exactly what you are after.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Global shipping, my branding, and an API so I can order my prints in software.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of drop ship printers out there. A few include:

- [White House Custom Color](http://www.whcc.com/)
- [MPIX](http://www.mpix.com/)
- [Bay Photo](http://bayphoto.com/)

I recommend looking at their web sites to determine if their needs suit your particular ones. Many local professional photographers in my area use these three services. I have used 2 of the 3 myself without issue.

Comment: I use both Mpix and WHCC, depending on quantity ordered.

Comment: One item I forgot to mention in my original answer. The top places allow you to get several samples either free or very reduced cost to help you get your settings down before printing.

Answer (score 7):

While not a traditional "print lab", there's a web service that integrates with several print labs and gives exactly what you want: [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/). I believe we hit all your requirements:

- All prints from SmugMug are drop shipped without the invoice.

  - Some items do ship with a workorder, but there's no prices on it.
- Pro account holders have several branding options:

  - sticker on the outside of the package for most orders
  - 4x6 thank you print included on most orders
  - your name on the return address of the package on many orders
- Pro account holders have access to several labs:

  - EZPrints in Atlanta, GA, USA
  - BayPhoto in Santa Cruz, CA, USA
  - WHCC in Eagan MN/Dallas TX/Fresno CA, USA
  - Loxley Colour in Scotland, UK
- There's [tons more functionality](http://www.smugmug.com/photos/photo-sharing-features/) beyond what you asked for.

(Disclaimer, not only do I work for SmugMug, but I do the integration work with the labs... so this is litterally tooting my own horn.)

Comment: +1 I <3 smugmug.  Their support alone makes them top notch.

Comment: I have used SmugMug quite a bit for my printing, coupling the services with customer service to make everything perfect and printed well has been great. Also the fact that customers (mother in my case) can order the prints she wants directly and I don't have to deal with the logistics

Comment: I like SmugMug, too, but I'm pretty sure they use Bay Photo for their "pro" prints.

Comment: @nwcs, BayPhoto is one option. There are four for pros to choose from as I mentioned in my answer. See the bottom right side of the homepage: https://img.skitch.com/20120413-dwpyp96c8jn4g7cxinam4ab9nx.jpg

Comment: @cabbey, the link to the API on http://www.smugmug.com/photos/photo-sharing-features/ is a little out of date...

Comment: yep, looks like it never got updated when the API docs moved. I'll get that updated so it doesn't have to rely on the redirect. Thanks @mattburns

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Filepress](http://www.filepress.co.uk).  I've been printing with them for the past few months and would definitely recommend their order fulfillment service: print quality is excellent and you can also backup your image files in your account.